# Create AWS Simple AD user and password from EC2 Linux instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, kerberos

I have an AWS Simple AD directory service configured and running. I have the DHCP Option Set configured to point DNS to the directory, and I have an EC2 Linux instance successfully joined the realm/domain.

Following the AWS blog article on [How to Manage Identities in Simple AD Directories](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-manage-identities-in-simple-ad-directories/), I tried adding a user and password:

```
$ net ads user ADD myuser Pa55word –C “Test User” –S corp.domain.com
```

However, when following this format an error is always thrown:

```
Could not add user myuser. Error setting password Operation not permitted
```

If you omit the optional password value, the user is successfully added:

```
$ net ads user ADD myuser –C “Test User” –S corp.domain.com
user myuseradded
```

But now I have a user without a password set. How can I now set this password (or successfully provide one at the time of user creation?).

Comment: So what exactly is an "AWS Simple AD directory service"?  How would that be different from say an "AWS *Full* AD directory service"?  The term seems odd.

Comment: @JohnRSmith The term is only odd unless you bother to look for it http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/directory_simple_ad.html

Comment: Guilty...as charged.  Thanks for throwing that link out there.

Comment: Was you able to find a solution , how was you able to manage the users in SimpleAD

Comment: @Shahbour Unfortunately not - I ended up using a Windows box to administer AD.

Comment: I was facing some issues for this same issue. Finally managed to make this working. https://devopslife.io/managing-aws-simplead-from-linux/